# Why do I receive empty lists using Pyusb library?

Tags: python, c, usb, stm32

I wish to read data from the internal flash memory of STM32F103C8T6(Blue Pill), I am using USB protocol to send the data from Blue Pill to my PC and using Pyusb v1.2.1 library.

**Code snippet-1** of how I am **Sending the data from the Blue Pill board(Slave)** when requested from master(PC):

```c
#define Read_Size 8192
uint8_t Read_Buffer[Read_Size];

if(Flash_Data_Transmission_Flag == 1){
    while(Flash_Address < 0x08010000){
        for(uint16_t j=0; j<Read_Size; j++){
            Read_Buffer[j] = *(__IO uint8_t *)Flash_Address;
            Flash_Address++;
        }
        CDC_Transmit_FS(Read_Buffer, sizeof(Read_Buffer));
    }
    if(Flash_Address == 0x08010000){
        Flash_Address = 0x0800C000;
    }
    Flash_Data_Transmission_Flag = 0;   //Reset Flag
}
```

Here, `Flash_Data_Transmission_Flag` is set from USB receive's Interrupt Service Routine, and I am reading 16KB of data.

**Code snippet-2** in Python, how I am doing the **Data handling on Pyusb receiving side(PC)**:

```py
DATA_BULK_WRITE_EP = 0x01
DATA_BULK_READ_EP  = 0x81
NUMBER_OF_BYTES_TO_READ = 8192
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=VID, idProduct = PID)
ep = dev[0].interfaces()[0].endpoints()[0]
dev.set_configuration()

Main_List = []

for i in range(0,2):
    dev.write(DATA_BULK_WRITE_EP, bytes(0x9), 1000)
    Main_List.append(dev.read(DATA_BULK_READ_EP, NUMBER_OF_BYTES_TO_READ, TIMEOUT))
```

`bytes(0x9)` is used as a command to set the `Flash_Data_Transmission_Flag`, so everytime Blue Pill(Slave) receives 9-Bytes, that should set `Flash_Data_Transmission_Flag` in ISR and execute the sequence written in the first **code snippet-1** above to start sending data read from defined memory address.

**Code snippet-3** USB Receive ISR to set the `Flash_Data_Transmission_Flag`

```c
static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
  USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[RANGE]);
  USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);
  uint16_t len = *Len;

  if(len == 9){
      Flash_Data_Transmission_Flag = 1;
  }
}
```

Here, `len==9` is checking the number of bytes received from code snippet-2, i.e. `bytes(0x9)`.

- **Expected Response:**

While receiving data on the pyusb side(code-block 2),
I should ideally be receiving 8192-bytes if I send first read command, and doing it twice should give me 16384 bytes that I append in the Main_List (Implemented in **code snippet-2**)

*Expected Structure of* `Main_List` : `[ [8192] [8192] ]` where `8192` are the total number of elements in the 1-D Sub_Lists.

- **Problem:**

When I run the **code snippet-2** in for loop for 2 times,
my `Main_List` receives: `[[8192][]]`. **I receive empty list second time**.

If I run it four times in a loop, my `Main_List` receives: `[[8192][][8192][]]`
and then I get 16384 bytes with 2 empty lists.

What could be causing this problem and how to get this correct?

- **More to the Problem:**

Even though running it 4 times in a loop gives me the expected result, the result is not consistent and provides erroneous data.

*Example:*
8Kb Image written to the internal flash memory:

[image: 8Kb Image written to the internal flash memory:]

Reading 16KB of Flash Memory expected Result:

[image]

Received erroneous outputs around 2-4 times in 20 runs and the pattern keeps changing:

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the image to flash correctly? Did you give it time to erase? Did you wait for every write operation to end before writing the next chunk to Flash? Just making sure the problem is where you think it is

Comment: @Ilya,  I erased the flash before writing and checked the written data using STM32CubeProgrammer. The data is written at the defined location only, it doesn't seem to be problematic to me. And the data is already written, so only reading it 20 times consecutively gives me this results, where I get the expecetd result most of the time but error-results sometimes as mentioned in the 'more to the problem' section.

Comment: How is `Read_Buffer` defined?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the USB receive ISR on the Blue Pill?

Comment: @pmacfarlane I have added the changes you asked, please check